# Show flex states according to condition

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4

I am creating a flex application. I have created one mxml file which having two spark states
State 1, State 2, one button and three checkbox. State 1 is a main mxml. When I click on button it goes to State 2. State 2 is another mxml whch I have imported into main mxml like

```
<summary:mySummary includeIn="mySummaryDetails" />
```

mySummary mxml also contains four different states.

My need is when I select checkbox from State 1 and click on button then according to selected checkbox I  want to  show perticular states from mySummary mxml. So how can I achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to check your checkbox selection inside your click method.

```
function buttonClick():void
{
  currentState = "State2";

  if(checkBox1.selected)
     mySummary.currentState = "mySummaryState1";

  if(checkBox2.selected)
     mySummary.currentState = "mySummaryState2";

  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add to you `click` method:

```
mySummary.currentState = "State1";
```

Comment: I have add this click method to my main mxml but my requirement is when I select checkbox from State 1 and click on button then according to selected checkbox I want to show perticular states from mySummary mxml because mySummary mxml also contains four states from that states I have display perticular states. Means Suppose I have select first checkbox then I want to dispaly only first state from mySummary state.